# CURLE_READ_ERROR on reading filename which contains foreign language characters

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, libcurl

I'm using `libcurl` to communicate with my `http` server. The functionality works fine until i try to read a file whose name is in foreign language. Let say the file name is `फ़ाइल.txt` and it is placed in the `std::wstring filePath` variable.

```
    CURLFORMcode formAddResult = curl_formadd(&formPost, &lastPtr, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file", CURLFORM_FILE, ws2s(filePath).c_str(), CURLFORM_END);

    if (formAddResult != CURL_FORMADD_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to add form data: " << curl_easy_strerror((CURLcode)formAddResult) << std::endl;
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        FreeLibrary(hCurlLib);
        return false;
    }
```

The above line of code returns:

`Failed to upload file: 26`

The above error is `CURLE_READ_ERROR`. This error indicates that the `libcurl` is unable to read from the specified file.

I'm converting the `std::wstring` to `std::string` using the below function

```
std::string ws2s(const std::wstring& wstr) {

    using convert_typeX = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;

    return converterX.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```

I'm doing something wrong in handling wide characters or conversion. I'm on VS-2019 and using the default `Unicode character set` in my project properties.

Comment: Just because you converted the UTF-16 filename to a UTF-8 string doesn't mean that curl will be able to _do_ anything with that UTF-8 string.

Comment: The best bet seems to be to read the file yourself and use the various `CURLFORM_BUFFER*` parameters to feed it to curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Botje, So here is the solution if someone needs it in future.

I have read the whole file in `std::vector fileBuffer` and then convert the filename to `UTF-8 encoded C-style string`

````
    // Convert the wstring filename to ```UTF-8``` encoded C-style string
    std::string filenameUtf8 = convertWStringToUTF8(filename);

    struct curl_httppost* formPost = nullptr;
    struct curl_httppost* lastPtr = nullptr;

    CURLFORMcode formAddResult = curl_formadd(&formPost, &lastPtr, 
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file", 
        CURLFORM_BUFFER, filenameUtf8.c_str(), 
        CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, fileBuffer.data(), 
        CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, fileBuffer.size(), 
        CURLFORM_END);
````

In case if you are wondering about `UTF-8` conversion,

```
std::string convertWStringToUTF8(const std::wstring& wstr) {
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> utf8_converter;
    return utf8_converter.to_bytes(wstr);
}
```